# Publish path too long

Tags: visual-studio-2012, publishing

I have an external library `fckEditor` which fails to publish because apparently the path name happens to be longer than `260` characters.  How do I get around this issue?

**Edit:** This is a visual studio issue, rather than the library I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Removing **delete all files before publish** option solved the problem for me.

Comment: that' doesn't work for me.  it's an inherent path length problem.